# Maintaining image clarity when zooming in

Tags: android, image, zooming

I implemented an application for image zooming based on [this tutorial](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/), and it works well.

However, when I zoom in on the image, it loses its clarity. I want to have image zooming that preserves quality and clarity. How can I set that up?

Comment: Are you saying your picture doesn't have infinite resolution? The only solution I can see is to use a higher resolution image, or possibly to use a better interpolation scheme but that only gets you so far.

Comment: http://www.ri.cmu.edu/publication_view.html?pub_id=3909 or http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5540206

Comment: can we convert jpg image into swf format?

Comment: If you're asking "can we vectorise an image" then the answer is yes but it's hard to automate in the general case.

Comment: then is there any another solution to maintain clerity of image?

Comment: The only general solution is to have a higher resolution picture than the scaled display of the highest zoom you're going to allow

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then awoodland's comment is right, and this is impossible. Despite what TV crime shows use as plot devices, you can't get infinite clarity out of any photograph. If you could, what would stop you from zooming in on any photo repeatedly until you got down to the molecular level?

When you zoom in on a digital image, what you're really doing is ignoring parts of the image and only looking at a small section of it. If you're starting with a zoomed-out image, then zooming in is like unfolding a crumpled-up dot-matrix printout and cutting out a square in the middle to look at; there was more information hidden in the crumpled area that you couldn't see before. But once you "unfold the paper all the way," that's it. If you try to look closer, you can make the individual dots (or pixels) bigger, but you don't get any more useful information because it's not there to begin with.

Converting to a vector image won't help you because of how vector images work. They save the relative positions of important points and then put down whatever size lines and shapes are needed to make a given size work. You can't reverse-engineer the rules from a single static image.

For example, if the top half of a 500px tall photo is solid blue, it could be because a rule says the top 250px of the image should be blue, or it could be because a rule says the top half of the image should be blue. If you're automatically converting to a vector image, the computer has no way to know which of those rules is correct, or if you happen to be looking at a special case of a much more complicated rule. As a result, your generated vector image would expand in completely inappropriate ways.